# If non-daemon thread is waiting for daemon one?

Tags: multithreading, jvm

If non-daemon thread is waiting for daemon thread (with `join()` method), will this prevent JVM from exit?

Answer (score 1):

> will this prevent JVM from exit?

Yes:-)

For threads created with the `threading` module, the main thread joins all non-daemon threads on exit.

If you have some non-daemon thread which is waiting for a lock, and you do not arrange for the lock to be released, then the main thread will hang on exit.

Comment: @SuzanCioc:- Sorry I just written it in a flow as I was working in Python. Updated my answer!!

Answer (score 0):

The method `wait()` waits for a signal (which can come from anywhere), and not for a particular thread (so your question is incorrectly worded).

So as long as non-daemon thread is waiting (does not matter what), jvm would not exit.